# Remove unknown characters in string using php

Tags: php, string, lumen

I have a simple string that has a value of this.
The value of this came from a biometrics fetcher

```
$name = "~DeviceName=TX628\x00";
```

I use this code to eliminate the excess character:

```
$x = trim($name, '~DeviceName=');
$deviceName = trim($x, '\x00');
```

but it only remove the **~DeviceName=**

```
$deviceName="TX628\x00"
```

when I **var_dump** this, It has a 6 string value but it should be 5 string value.

```
string(6) "TX628"
```

> Thank you for all the answer. This code below works for my problem.

```
$name = "~DeviceName=TX628\x00";
$x = trim($name, '~DeviceName=');
$deviceName = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $x);
//$deviceName = TX628;
```

Comment: you say you want to remove "unknown" characters, but then you remove known strings. Can you clarify what exactly you want remove and what you want to get? Also, note that trim doesnt accept substrings, but a set of chars, so the first trim will remove ~DeviceName= but also NmaDvice~= or any combination, e.g. if your TX628 is DN123, the D and N will also get removed.

Comment: try to do this:
$deviceName = trim($x, '\\x00');, I puted it in my solution, check it

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does not work is that the `\x00` argument for `trim` function is in single quotes, instead of double quotes, i.e. the following will work

```
$name = "~DeviceName=TX628\x00";
$x = trim($name, '~DeviceName=');
$deviceName = trim($x, "\x00");
```

Please note, that `trim` is not supposed to be used for removing strings, just selected bytes. If the device name was for example `DX628`, the result would be just `X628`, because the first `trim` would remove the initial `D` byte as well.

To safely remove string from start of another string, you should use for example `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to remove non printable characters

```
$string = preg_replace( '/[^[:cntrl:]]/', '',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### that is because \x is a character with hex code

so \x00 is a zero so `"\x00" == "\0"`

you might have a hex string in the name, or in the trim

you should have even normal string in both or hex in both

why dont you try to use double escape. So:

```
$deviceName = trim($x, '\\x00');
```

read this from php docs:
[php escape sequence..](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$name = "~DeviceName=TX628\x00";


$x = trim($name, '~DeviceName=');

$x=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $x);



 var_dump ($x);
```

That seemed easy but took me some effort. So here is your solution. It returns 5 as it should be. the \x00 are named "control characters" so next time you face this problem look for this tag to see which other control characters exist in order to replace them the same way.

The output is : `string(5) "TX628"`